# Unable to create a Rails app due to incompatible library version - load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

First-time post here! I am trying to build a rails app but I am having a ton of difficulty getting started. I have installed Rails, and Ruby but every time I go to make the app (Miless-MBP:railstest miles$ rails new tester2) I get a multitude of errors. The full log is below, but I have listed the 4 here.

Thank you all so much!

```
/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)

/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)

/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)

/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
```

````
    26: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    25: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    24: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    22: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    20: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    18: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    17: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    16: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    15: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    13: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    11: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     5: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     3: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     1: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    26: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    25: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    23: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     2: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    26: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    25: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    23: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
     3: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     1: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    28: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    26: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    24: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    22: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    20: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    19: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    18: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    17: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    15: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/miles/railstest/tester2/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    13: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    11: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
     5: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
     4: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     2: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)```
````

Comment: Hey, Have you able to installed msgpack in your local machine successfully?

Comment: Hi @Asmita I have not. Do you know you how I would do so?

Comment: @TalaatMagdy would you possibly be able to elaborate? Thanks for the help so far though!

Comment: Okay -- so now I have installed msgpack. The only error I get now is:

```/Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/miles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.bundle (LoadError)```

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue. You need to completely clean out the `msgpack` gem using:

```
gem uninstall msgpack
```

Then reinstall it, so that the libraries are built against the version of ruby you're now using.

You could also try:

```
bundle install --redownload
```

which should reinstall the gems and rebuild the linked libraries with the version of ruby you're now using.

Comment: `bundle install --redownload` works for me. Mine got into a bad state because I was using rvm and I installed the wrong version and tried to install a new version of ruby, but they are on the same minor version. For example, I first installed 2.7.2 and then tried to upgrade to 2.7.5.

Comment: worked like charm !

Comment: Thanks!! `bundle install --redownload ` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I just spend several hours on a very similar error, after upgrading a Ruby app from ruby 2.4 to 2.6. I'm using rbenv and bundler on MacOS Mojave.

I can't pinpoint how I fixed it, but after trying lots of updates/rehash/install approaches with little success, I uninstalled about a dozen old versions of ruby and started clean. This got me past the exact error in the question.

This may be overkill, but it worked for me:

List all installed ruby versions:

```
rbenv versions
```

Uninstall all versions of Ruby.

```
rbenv uninstall 2.1
rbenv uninstall 2.1.9
etc.
```

Install needed version(s) of Ruby

```
rbenv install

bundle install
```

I tried running my app after `bundle install` and got dozens of warnings like these:

```
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.8.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.8.0
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring bootsnap-1.4.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.4.6
Ignoring bootsnap-1.4.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.4.5
```

At that time, I could not run `bundle exec rake`

```
% bundle exec rake
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Running `bundle` appeared successful, but did not update Gemfile.lock, and did not fix the problem.

Finally, restoring all the gems to pristine solved the problem:

```
gem pristine --all
```

Note - gem pristine --all took like a half hour. I'm confused on how these gems got to be in other-than-pristine condition. But...it's working now. I can run the app, rake, etc.

Comment: `gem pristine --all` was the fix for me